# replace dots in a string with a character in bash

Tags: bash

i have a string like `1.1.1.1.1` , i want to replace all dots with `_` character.

i wrote the following program:

```
#!/bin/bash

var="1.1.1.1.1"
new2=${var/./_}
echo $new2
```

but it just replaces first dot with `_` in the string, so the result is:
 `1_1.1.1.1`

how i can replace all dots with `_` ?

thanks.

Comment: use the regex /g for global

Comment: @happymacarts That's not how you make global replacements in a parameter expansion.

Comment: Thats what i get for posting a comment in a thread I know nothing about... At least i didn't try to answer it!

Answer (score 31):

You were pretty close. To replace *all* matches, use `${var//find/replace}`:

```
#!/bin/bash
var="1.1.1.1.1"
new2="${var//./_}"
echo "$new2"       # prints 1_1_1_1_1
```

The bash built-ins of the form `${var...}` are called *parameter expansions/substitutions*. They are documented in detail in [the official bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion). For an alternative explanation, check out [bash-hackers.org](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe).